# Assigning Value to Property while iterating a list(of T)

Tags: vb.net

Can't find any help for this and the `Similar Questions` stackoverflow is suggesting while writing this offer no help either.

I want to set the values of multiple property(s) while iterating a `For i = 0` loop while having the Property and Value each in a list, I'm trying to do this using the Index of the For Loop to choose both the Value and Property.

What I've tried so far is below, albeit cut down for this question, but it doesn't set any value to the Property(s) it just stores it within the list `mPropList` itself and i need to store the values as properties (or bog standard Variables, but i'd prefer Property(s))

```
Public Class IDC

    Private mPropList As new List(Of Object)From {pID, pCat, pNum, pVer}
    Private mFieldList as New List(Of String) From {"ID", "Cat", "Num", "Ver"}

    Friend Property pID() As String
       Get
           Return mID
       End Get
       Set(value As String)      'Same setup for the other Properties
           mID = value
       End Set
    End Property

...

    Sub New()

        For i = 0 To mFieldList.Count - 1
            mPropList(i) = mFieldList(i)
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

The above works wonderful if I want to only take values from `mPropList` but I need to take values from `pID,pCat...`

```
Output:

List Values:    
mPropList(0) = ID
mPropList(1) = Cat
mPropList(2) = Num
mPropList(3) = Ver

Property Values:
pID = Nothing
pCat = Nothing
pNum = Nothing
pVer = Nothing
```

I hope I've explained this correctly and not cut down the code above to much and broke it. I just can't seem to find a direct answer to this and don't want to have to create 'another' class to do manage this or create more code. But if another class is the only way I guess I have no choice.

But if the above idea can be made to work I have several other places in my code I can apply this, so fingers crossed.

Any help would be nice.

**EDIT:** The use of `New List(Of String) From {"ID", "Cat", "Num", "Ver"}` is only to show values that *'could'* be in the list, in reality is populated by a Access OLEDB Read command.

**EDIT2:** It's more of a 'can it be done' curiosity than 'should it be done' as I'm new I'm trying to experiment and find different ways of doing things in hopes of learning...

Comment: You could use reflection but that seems to be an odd requirement. In most cases there are much better approaches. Why do you need that? If you have a list of related informations, why don't you use that list. Or maybe: use a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`. The key would be f.e. `ID`.

Comment: The use of `New List(Of String) From {"ID", "Cat", "Num", "Ver"}` is only to show values that *'could'* be in the list, in reality is populated by a Access OLEDB Read command.
Also, I'm not familiar with what `reflection` is, so i'm going to look up that.

Comment: But why can't you select the appropriate columns from the data reader and assign it to the right property?

Comment: Use something like `New List(Of Object) From {Function() Return pID, Function() Return pCat, ...}` instead, so that you will always get the updated values (don't know if this will work though, writing from my phone).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I did try it that way and it did work. However because I'm quite new to VB.net and programming in general. It's more of a 'can it be done' curiosity than 'should it be done'. I understand going directly from Data Reader to Property is possible, but as i'm new i'm trying to experiment and find different ways of doing things in hopes of learning... The reason I'm doing it this way is to try and make a `Blank Class` where i can supply it a couple of lists (or a Tuple) and it will spit out a different answer depending on what lists i gave it.... If that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies If I've got hold of wrong end of t'stick - could you just use a collection of the idc class, and iterate through that using a for each loop? (an observablecollection(of T) if you want to handle notifcations)....

Ok some quick (and very dirty!) code as requested. Not sure if its wot you want but here goes......Resource is an existing class of mine which I import in.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Resource.Resource
Module Module1

    Public collplay As New Collection(Of Resource.Resource)

    Sub Main()
        Dim tempres As New Resource.Resource
        Dim tempres2 As New Resource.Resource
        tempres.Name = "supaStix"
        tempres.ShortName = "stix"
        collplay.Add(tempres)
        tempres2.Name = "FredBloggs"
        tempres2.ShortName = "Bloggs"
        collplay.Add(tempres2)
        Dim reit As New Resource.Resource
        For Each reit In collplay
            Console.Write(reit.Name.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

In the for each loop each property of Resource is available to do with whatever you want feed lists, write to DB whatever.

I'm not entirely sure I've grasped what you want to do though, so again apologies if I'm barking up t'wrong tree.....

Updated 29/04 with simple example of an ObservableCollection.....

a simple Win Forms App.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Resource.Resource
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim collres As New ObservableCollection(Of Resource.Resource)


    For x = 1 To 4

        Dim singleres As New Resource.Resource

        singleres.ShortName = "Stix" & x.ToString
        singleres.Name = "SupaStix" & x.ToString
        collres.Add(singleres)

    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = collres

End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Result]

And from MSDN:-

***In many cases the data that you work with is a collection of objects. For example, a common scenario in data binding is to use an ItemsControl such as a ListBox, ListView, or TreeView to display a collection of records.
You can enumerate over any collection that implements the IEnumerable interface. However, to set up dynamic bindings so that insertions or deletions in the collection update the UI automatically, the collection must implement the INotifyCollectionChanged interface. This interface exposes the CollectionChanged event, an event that should be raised whenever the underlying collection changes.
WPF provides the ObservableCollection(Of T) class, which is a built-in implementation of a data collection that implements the INotifyCollectionChanged interface.
Before implementing your own collection, consider using ObservableCollection(Of T) or one of the existing collection classes, such as List(Of T), Collection(Of T), and BindingList(Of T), among many others. If you have an advanced scenario and want to implement your own collection, consider using IList, which provides a non-generic collection of objects that can be individually accessed by index. Implementing IList provides the best performance with the data binding engine.

To fully support transferring data values from binding source objects to binding targets, each object in your collection that supports bindable properties must implement an appropriate property changed notification mechanism such as the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.***

Comment: I have yet to try iterating through a Class so i'm unsure of how to do that. And I don't know what a observablecollection(of T) is, but i'm going to find out. Would you be able to edit your response and show a example of what you mean?

Comment: I don't have an easily followed observablecollection I can show - I've used it when databinding to a WPF control. I wouldn't worry about it until you start databinding

Answer (score 0):

You want to access the real properties of your IDC class through a list of properties. As Visual Vincent has mentioned in a comment, you can use property accessors, i.e. delegates. Create a class of property accessors and property names.

```
Class PropertyAccessor
    Public Sub New(name As String, getVal As Func(Of Object), setVal As Action(Of Object))
        Me.Name = name
        Me.GetValue = getVal
        Me.SetValue = setVal
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Name As String
    Public ReadOnly GetValue As Func(Of Object)
    Public ReadOnly SetValue As Action(Of Object)
End Class
```

In you IDC class you can now declare and initialize the properties list like this:

```
Private mPropList As List(Of PropertyAccessor)

Public Sub New()
    mPropList = New List(Of PropertyAccessor)() From {
        New PropertyAccessor("pID", Function() pID, Sub(value) pID = DirectCast(value, String)),
        New PropertyAccessor("pCat", Function() pCat, Sub(value) pCat = DirectCast(value, String)),
        New PropertyAccessor("pNum", Function() pNum, Sub(value) pNum = CInt(value)),
        New PropertyAccessor("pVer", Function() pVer, Sub(value) pVer = DirectCast(value, String))
    }
End Sub
```

Basically the `PropertyAccessor` contains variables to which you can assign a Function (`GetValue`) and a Sub (`SetValue`). You can define them using inline functions and subs called [Lambda Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx).

Values can be set and read like this:

```
Public Sub SetValues()
    mPropList(0).SetValue("some id")
    mPropList(1).SetValue("my category")
    mPropList(2).SetValue(123)
    mPropList(3).SetValue("1.0")
End Sub

Public Sub PrintValues()
    For Each prop As PropertyAccessor In mPropList
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue())
    Next
End Sub
```

You can also use [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in VB and don't need to declare a backing variable:

```
Public Property pID As String
Public Property pCat As String
Public Property pNum As Integer
Public Property pVer As String
```